# How to apply MathJax LaTeX formatting to <div> programatically?

Tags: mathjax

For example, if I add a `<div>` to a page via (assume jQuery is included)

```
$('body').append($('<div>').text('x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.'));
```

How can I apply the "tex2jax" formatting to that `<div>`? I don't want MathJax to automatically run on any of my text; I want to apply it manually whenever I add an element to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `script` tag instead of `div`, then schedule reprocessing of the page:

```
$('body').append($('<script type="math/tex">').text('x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.'));
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGz6s/2/)